# Compiling WebRTC native client API for RTCDataChannel file sharing

Tags: c++, webrtc, gyp

I am trying to build a command-line native application that supports:

- native - native
- native - browser
- browser - browser

file sharing using the WebRTC data channel. However I cannot seem to figure out how to use the native WebRTC c++ API (http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started - successfully got to the end).

I have successfully built the example peerconnection_client & peerconnection_client (on Linux), however the client crashes when trying to share video (I'm not worried, as I only need the data transfer to work, not audio or video). However I have been unable to compile my own app which links into the WebRTC library.

Comment: "I have been unable to compile" -- don't leave us hanging!  What happens when you try?